# Unable to connect amazon ec2 hadoop instance from outside cluster

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have setup amazon ec2 instance and installed hadoop-1.0.4 single node, started all hadoop components, and working fine.

I tested hadoop cluster by uploading file using hadoop command and working fine.

When i am accessing hadoop cluster through java code, I am getting following exception

failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information

/etc/hosts file

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1   ec2-x.x.x.x.compute-1.amazonaws.com ip-x.x.x.x.ec2.internal
```

core-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://ec2-x.x.x.x.compute-1.amazonaws.com:54310</value>
  </property>
```

Could you please help me to fix this ?

Complete print Stack trace is

```
: Call to ec2-X.X.X.X.compute-1.amazonaws.com/X.X.X.X:54310 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.wrapException(

Client.java:1099)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(

Client.java:1075)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(

RPC.java:225)
at $Proxy7.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)

at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(

RPC.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(

RPC.java:379)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createRPCNamenode(

DFSClient.java:119)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(

DFSClient.java:238)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(

DFSClient.java:203)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(

DistributedFileSystem.java:89)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(

FileSystem.java:1386)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(

FileSystem.java:66)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(

FileSystem.java:1404)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(

FileSystem.java:254)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(

FileSystem.java:123)
at org.bigpeep.upload.custom.SolrIndexMapReduce.run(

SolrIndexMapReduce.java:45)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(

ToolRunner.java:65)
at org.bigpeep.upload.dal.FileDaoImpl.indexDoc(

FileDaoImpl.java:370)
at org.bigpeep.upload.service.FileServiceImpl.indexDocument(

FileServiceImpl.java:96)
at org.bigpeep.upload.service.FileServiceImplTest.testuploadFile(

FileServiceImplTest.java:48)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(

Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(

NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(

DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(

Method.java:597)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(

FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(

ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(

FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(

InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(

RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(

RunAfters.java:31)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(

BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(

BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(

ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(

ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(

ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(

ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(

ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(

ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(

JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(

TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(

RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(

RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(

RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(

RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by:

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(

Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(

SocketChannelImpl.java:574)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(

SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(

NetUtils.java:489)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(

Client.java:434)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(

Client.java:560)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2000(

Client.java:184)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(

Client.java:1206)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(

Client.java:1050)
```

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace of the error?

Comment: The ec2 security group usually prohibits the access from outside, so I would check that first.

Comment: Thomas, COuld you please provide the corresponding security groups that i need to check?